# Translation of “data scientist”

Tags: traduction, anglais, science

I read that data science can be translated to [science des données](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_des_donn%C3%A9es). How would you say "*data scientist*” in French?

My ideas:

- analyseur de données
- analyseur de grosses données
- scientifique de données

In the 01net article [Coupe du monde : le logiciel qui peut faire gagner l'Allemagne ce soir](http://www.01net.com/editorial/623742/le-big-data-le-douzieme-homme-de-lequipe-allemande-de-foot/), they say:

> L’Allemagne semble aujourd’hui être la seule équipe de la Coupe du
> monde de football à être aussi avancée dans le domaine. Des
> statisticiens ou **data-scientists** ont déjà rejoint le staff qui coache
> l’équipe, travaillant de concert avec les techniciens qui étudient de
> façon plus classique les vidéos de chaque match. Mais d’autres équipes
> vont certainement suivre la tendance big data et s’équiper de tels
> outils pour les prochaines compétitions.

which I found a bit weird.

Comment: *Analyseur* est un outil, *analyste* est celui qui manipule l'analyseur - La 3ème proposition est celle retenue par *Linguee* : http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=data-scientist

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, even if France, "analyste de données" is rarely used... We call them "spécialiste en data-mining" when it is related with big data, or only "analystes", because obviously, you will analyse data. :)

Answer (score 4):

> **Analystes de données**

est plus couramment utilisé.

Answer (score 2):

> *Expert/experte en science des données* ([GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26527138))
> *Expert/experte en mégadonnées* ([GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26527138))
>
> « En France, le terme *expert en mégadonnées* et sa variante sont
> recommandés officiellement par la Commission d'enrichissement de la
> langue française, depuis 2017. » ([GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26527138) ; [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=expert%20en%20m%C3%A9gadonn%C3%A9es&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search))

*Contra* [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=DATA%20SCIENTIST&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Un nuance de sens entre *scientifique* et *expert* peut être utile dans certains contextes.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirais ***Scientifique des données***, en calque sur l'anglais, parce que c'est un concept qui est calqué sur l'anglais et puis voilà. La [page wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_des_donn%C3%A9es) fait ça aussi, entre autres.

En particulier, ça maintient la différence avec le titre d'*analyste* (analyste d'affaires, analyste programmeur, analyste fonctionnel...) qui existait bien avant la *Data Science*.

Comment: Pourquoi est-il important de maintenir cette différence ? Entre un analyste financier et un analyste fonctionnel, le job est très différent et pourtant ils ont le terme "analyste" dans leur fonction...

Comment: Un peu de variété, pour aider à simplifier les choses, pourquoi pas ? Bien sur, on pourrait cultiver l'ambiguité, mais... bof.